# Compile error while declaring close

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Platform : Microsoft Visual Basic 6.5 and MS Excel 2007

I am trying to do a macro to do some editing to an excel enable file. Done research on how to close the Excel file without saving. The [webpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.close%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) teaches me to put declaration before I can use the method. I insert copy the command in and try to compile. Got compilation error, expected end of statement. Anyone know what's wrong with the declaration?

```
Public Overridable Sub Close ( _
    <OptionalAttribute> SaveChanges As Object, _
    <OptionalAttribute> Filename As Object, _
    <OptionalAttribute> RouteWorkbook As Object _
)

Private Sub WorkbookClose()
    Me.Close(False, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question. Why are you closing the workbook this way. How are you opening this workbook? Manually or via Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its macro in excel copy the below code to thisworkbook section of code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Me.Close False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: HiHi Santosh. Thank you. This is the function i need. thanks a lot =)

Comment: Santosh i hope u see this msg, i wanted to write similar function for words too...

I used the same method you mention above and replaced the Me.Close False with the below coding
but cannot work...

Tried to use 

1) Me.close
2) Me.close(false)

3) ActiveDocument.Close

4) ActiveDocument.Close (false)

5) ActiveDocument.Quit

6) Application.Quit (False)

7) Application.Close

8) ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

Comment: Private Sub Document_Close()  Me.Close End Sub  Please enter this code to ThisDocument of Word.

Comment: Santosh
it prompt me command error when i tried to close the document

Answer (score 1):

Double click on "ThisWorkbook" and enter the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Save Is Not Allowed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx Potter, though this is not the script i needed. thank for the reference.